# Facebook's mobile app/site horizontal slide menu : Jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, plugins, slider

Does anybody know a good horizontal slide menu jquery plugin that could emulate Facebook's relatively new mobile site/app's menu?

Basically you have a view of all the content, and when you click a button, a menu slides from the left, moving the content a little to the right (to the width of the menu sliding in). When a button on the menu is clicked, the menu slides out of view, the content slides back, and then changes corresponding to whatever menu button was clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing.

The best example I can find is a paid mobile Wordpress theme:
http://themeforest.net/item/hotcake-mobile-business-html-template/1065437

Pretty slick and you could at least see how it is done.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Aldomatics code doesn't behave well in windows phone and doesn't handle orientation issues

This topic is old but here is a working solution for mobile devices (Build with Jquery) :

it's working on Windows phone, iOs and Android Devices.

I've tried to keep the code as simple as possible, it's easy to understand and modifiy.

http://apptitudes.github.com/SlidingMenuJS/

Answer (score 0):

I find this implementation the best example currently available:

https://github.com/aldomatic/FB-Style-Page-Slide-Menu

It's not a jQuery plug-in, per se, but it should to the trick!